# Is it right for chain rule in trace function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, trace, matrix-rank

The objective function is 
$$
f(X)=\min_X trace(B^TX^TCXBD)
$$
we know the following derivatives from [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf),
$$
\frac{\delta{trace(B^TX^TCXB)}}{\delta X}=C^TXBB^T+CXBB^T \\
\frac{\delta trace(XD)}{\delta X}=D^T
$$
then, is it reasonable for the following rule?
$$
\frac{\delta f(X)}{\delta X}=\frac{\delta f(X)}{\delta \{B^TX^TCXB\}}\cdot \frac{\delta{trace(B^TX^TCXB)}}{\delta X}=D^T(C^TXBB^T+CXBB^T)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,I've found the following relations
$$
tr(ABC)=tr(BCA)=tr(CAB)
$$
then, we have
$$
tr(B^TX^TCXBD)=tr(CXBDB^TX^T)
$$
then, from the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf), we have
$$
\frac{\delta{tr(EXFX^TG)}}{\delta X}=E^TG^TXF^T+GEXF
$$
then, let
$$
E=C,F=BD,G=I
$$
we could get the answer.

Comment: There's never a need to apologize for finding your own answer!

Comment: @MichaelGrant, thank you!